# 「App Store Connect」で各バージョンの配信アプリのリストが10個までしか見ることができない

Tags: ios, apple

Appleの「App Store Connect」で使用する「TestFlight」に関する質問です．

各バージョンの配信アプリのリストが最大10個表示されますが，
**最近の10個までが表示され，それ以前のものを見ることができません．**

[ビルド]番号の昇順／降順を切り替えることで最初の10個を見ることができますが，やはりそれ以後のものは見ることができません．

配信先を追加したり，配信を停止したりすることができずに困っています．
解決方法をご存知の方いましたらご教授ください．よろしくお願い致します．

WindowsのChrome, MacのChrome/Safariで同様の状態です．

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

こちら，二週間ほど前にApple（Japan）に電話で問い合わせして，その後メールで以下の回答を貰いました．

- 最大表示数は10個
- App Store Connect API を使用すれば全ビルド情報を取得できる
- それ以上はTSI（テクニカルサポート）で質問してください

ですが，本日TestFlightで
「さらに表示」ボタンが付いており，全てのビルドが確認できるようになっている
ことに気づきました．
ここ二週間で戻ったようです．